# Questions about classes and imports

Tags: python, class, program-entry-point

I'm using python 2.7 32 bit on Ubuntu 14.04. This is a bit hard to describe, but i'm trying to use variables from the "__ main __" of a class.

Here is the main.py file:

```
import time

class Test:
    def __init__(self):
        self.var1 = 1
        self.var2 = "foo"
        import less

        self.a = less.c()

    def run(self):
        self.a.update()

d = Test()

while True:
    time.sleep(0.2)
    d.run()
```

Here is the other less.py file:

```
from __main__ import Test

class c:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = "a"
        self.b = "b"

    def update(self):
        if (Test.var1 == 1):
            print(self.a)
```

When I run the main.py script, the terminal throws this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    file "main.py", line 18, in <module>
        d.run
    file "main.py", line 12, in run
        self.a.update()
    file "/home/username/Workspace/less.py", line 9, in update
        if (Test.var1 == 1):
   AttributeError: class Test has no attribute "var1"
```

My question is why does the less.py not find an attribute in the class Test.

Comment: It's all about scopes I think.

Comment: The class `Test` really doesn't have an attribute `var1`.  Instances of the class might have that attribute, but the class doesn't.  This is unrelated to your file structure -- you can reproduce this with a single file as well.

Comment: why are you using `from __main__`

Comment: @SvenMarnach The reason i'm using 2 files is because this is a very dumbed down version of a much bigger project. Also, how would I access the instance's attribute, as it also throws an error.

Comment: When you try and access it through an instance, what error is thrown?

Answer (score 1):

Your immediate error is because class `Test` has no attribute `var1`.  The instances of `Test` have that attribute, because they have executed the `__init__` method which creates the attribute.

BTW: you should not import `__main__`, it will eventually be bad news.  Define your class in another module, and import that new module into both your main file and the other files that need the class.

Answer (score 0):

Comments and a answer already give you correct way to fix your problem.
To fix it instantly modify your code like following.
But eventually I think you need to know difference of class and instance variables.
Refer to '[Class and Instance Variables](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#class-and-instance-variables)' document.

```py
class Test:
    var1 = None
    var2 = None

    def __init__(self):
        Test.var1 = 1
        Test.var2 = "foo"
        import less
```